# C++ Iterate over template variable instantiations

Tags: c++, templates

Take a look at this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
std::vector<T> vec{};

int main() {
    vec<short>.push_back(5);
    vec<int>.push_back(10);
    vec<long int>.push_back(15);
}
```

The `vec` variable is templated, but there is no telling what possible instantiations occurred. In this case it is clear: `short`, `int` and `long`. But what about more complex cases? How do I track template instantiations?

My goal is to be able to **iterate over all `vec` instances**. Something like

```
for (std::any element : vec) {
    delete element; // Or any common logic the types might have (can guarantee with concepts)
}
```

Comment: "The vec variable is templated" No, you have a template that instantiates variable*s*. `vec` is not a variable. `vec<int>` is a different variable to `vec<short>`.

Comment: @Caleth please edit the question

Comment: delete isn't an operation common to integers.

Comment: There are no operations common to all types

Comment: @eerorika there are no restrictions on what `vec` might hold. This is pseudocode.

Comment: @Caleth `typeid`

Comment: Ok, there are no operations that can be usefully applied to values of unconstrained types, and not the types themselves

Comment: Actually there is one thing you can do: you can erase elements from each `vec`

Comment: @Caleth I can use a concept that ensures that `operator<<` is defined and print everything to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do something if you wrap `vec` in a function, and have a type-erased "do things to `vec<T>`" interface.

You will need to specify all the things you want to do to the various `vec<T>()`s up front.

```
template <typename T>
concept printable = requires (T t) { std::cout << t; }

template <printable T>
std::vector<T> & vec();

struct vec_printer
{
    vec_printer(std::type_index index) : index(index) {}

    virtual ~vec_printer() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;
    // etc...

    std::type_index index;
};

struct vec_printer_compare 
{
    using ptr = std::unique_ptr<vec_printer>;
    bool operator(const ptr & lhs, const ptr & rhs){ return lhs->index < rhs->index; }
};

std::set<std::unique_ptr<vec_printer>, vec_printer_compare> vec_printers;

template <printable T>
struct vec_printer_impl
{
    vec_printer_impl() : vec_printer(typeid(T)) {}
    void thing_one() { for (auto & v : vec<T>()) { std::cout << v; } }
};

template <printable T>
std::vector<T> & vec()
{
    vec_printers.emplace(std::make_unique<vec_printer_impl<T>>());
    static std::vector<T> v;
    return v;
}

void print_vecs()
{
    for (auto & printer : vec_printers) { printer->print(); }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the big ol static function variable trick. Slipped my mind completely